# Unexpected identifier in a custom twig / Sonata and Symfony 2

Tags: javascript

I have a custom twig that extends the

```
base_list_field.html.twig
```

from Sonata Admin Generator.

Inside my custom twig, I've just have this code

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
<div>
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/aaaadmin/images/map_magnify.png') }}"  
    onclick="alert('Clic sur l'image');"  
    style="cursor:pointer;" >
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The icon is well displayed into a column, and if I pass the mouse over the icon, I see the cursor changed to "pointer".
But when I click on the map, I have an

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I can't figure out why.

Comment: You have an unescaped apostrophe (`'`) in your onclick event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the onclick :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
<div>
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/inerisadmin/images/map_magnify.png') }}"  
    onclick="alert('Clic sur l\'image');"  
    style="cursor:pointer;" >
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

You have to escape simple quote